# SQL Query to compare two columns with one column from another table (and get two values)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

Is it possible to, based on the ID value of two columns from `table1`, get their equivalent in `table2`?

My `table1` looks like this:

```
id | origin | destiny
-- | ------ | -------
1  | 2      | 3
2  | 4      | 5
```

and `table2`, like this:

```
id | name
-- | ----
1  | bla
2  | asd
3  | dfg
4  | qwe
5  | tle
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
id | origin | destiny | nameOrigin | nameDestiny
-- | ------ | ------- | ---------- | -----------
1  | 2      | 3       | asd        | dfg
2  | 4      | 5       | qwe        | tle
```

I tried to do two queries:

```
SELECT
    t1.origin, 
    t1.destiny,
    t2.name
FROM 
    table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.origin = t2.id
```

and:

```
SELECT
    t1.origin, 
    t1.destiny,
    t2.name as destinyName
FROM 
    table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.destiny = t2.id
```

But if I delete a value from one table, the another one keeps indexing that row hence there is an undefined offset problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the second table twice:

```sql
SELECT      t1.id,
            t1.origin, 
            t1.destiny,
            o.name as nameOrigin,
            d.name as nameDestiny
FROM        table1 t1 
INNER JOIN  table2 o ON t1.origin = o.id
INNER JOIN  table2 d ON t1.destiny = d.id
```

NB: *"destiny"* is not the same thing as *"destination"*.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple query:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.origin,t1.destiny,o.name as nameOrigin, d.name as nameDestiny  
FROM t1,t2 o, t2 d 
WHERE t1.origin=o.id AND t1.destiny=d.id
```

I am attaching SQL fiddle link here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecf5ae